# Есть ли бесплатные API для получения сведений по книгам?

Tags: api

Есть площадка `https://isbndb.com/apidocs`, но она платная. Есть ли нечто подобное бесплатное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, [Open Library](https://openlibrary.org/). Запрос выглядит как-то так:

```
http://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:1931498717&jscmd=details&format=json
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, долго не мог найти.